# Trying to query Wordpress posts only if Featured Image is set

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to run a Wordpress query to only return posts that have the Featured Image set. This is what I have tried in my query but it is not working:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS'
    )
)
```

I know I can run `if(has_post_thumbnail($post->ID))` to see if the Featured Image is set once the posts are returned, however I don't want to waste memory traversing through every post to see if the image is set, so I'm hoping to query *only* those that have it set.

Can someone help with why my code doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; // pagination

$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => -1, // optional to overwrite the dashboard setting
'paged' => $paged,
'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id'
);
query_posts($args);     ?>
```

### [As solved here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/get_posts-with-thumbnail-only)

### [get_posts with thumbnail only](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/get_posts-with-thumbnail-only)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=post&posts_per_page=10&paged='. get_query_var('paged')); ?>
  <?php if( have_posts() ): ?>
         <?php while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>

 <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>">

<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Its just a simple code for show only features image from posts.